# Are ties still worn with suits?

Tags: dress-code, australia

I live in Melbourne Australia, and one day I wore a suit and tie to work because I had to do my corporate photo. Whilst I was having lunch I took a look around (this is in the city) and I couldn't see one solitary person other than myself wearing a tie with their suit, out of literally hundreds of people (this wasn't Friday either). There were people with suits, but they didn't have ties. I then felt like I was sticking out like a sore thumb because I was wearing a tie. Although the instructions were to wear a tie for the photo shoot, I suspect they had not been updated for a long time, and it may have been acceptable not to have a tie. So my question is, are people still wearing ties with their suits? Or now that big corporations are moving to be more casual (at least here in Australia) are ties a thing of the past?

Comment: Depends on the country, In Japan the majority wears ties. And I heard( I am not Japanese but I am in Japan)  that " You can never overdress ". If you don't know how formal it is, better be more formal then less.

Comment: Yeah, the trend in Australia has been to move away from the business suits and ties - it depends a bit on local or office culture, but the typical clothing is smart casual these days: https://www.google.com.au/search?tbm=isch&q=australia+smart+casual+men

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen both, but it usually depends on the crowd.  Like around Gov. folks ties seem like a staple, but around more commercial the classic button up shirt with a blazer is in style and even jeans with that sometimes.  I think it varies with country and business type too, so I'd expect a variety of answers to this one.  In general though I think the more formal business attire is being relaxed from where it used to be.

Comment: Gov. in particular seems a land of extremes: either suit and tie, or no suit at all. Plenty of casualwearers there too.